# Devilspie2 lua script to open all bluej applications at specified position.

Tags: lua, bluej

I got a .lua script for devilspie2 that I'm trying to get to work. The scripts purpose is to force all bluej windows to open at at specified position. I can only get the Main window to launch at the specified position. All the other bluej windows that opens from within the main bluej window ignore this rule. Here is the script code.

```
--Start Bluej at specified position. 
if (get_application_name()=="bluej-Boot") then
   -- x,y-coordinates, xsize, ysize
   set_window_position(2655,197);
end
```

And here is the devilspie2 documentation. [Devilspie2](http://www.gusnan.se/devilspie2/manual.php#get_application_name)

As you can see I use the get_application_name() to check against the string literal "bluej-boot" and this works well for the main application. The problem is that the windows that are opened from within bluej don't have the same application name. It gets renamed to match the window name. How can I identify those windows and apply the same rules towards them as the main window?

Answer (score 0):

Use the "-d" option while the target windows are open, with a cfg like this :

```
gwc=get_window_class()
gwt=get_window_type()
gan=get_application_name()
gcin=get_class_instance_name()

debug_print("Window name: " .. get_window_name());
debug_print("Application name: " .. gan);
debug_print("Window type: " .. gwt);
debug_print("Window role: " .. get_window_role());
debug_print("Window class: " .. gwc);
debug_print("Class instance: " .. gcin);
x, y, width, height = get_window_geometry();
debug_print("X: "..x..", Y: "..y..", width: "..width..", height: "..height);
debug_print("--------------------------------------------------")
```

and see what strings you can use to select them.